I'm seeing "The response is not a valid JSON response." on a wordpress site
I am tryign to build a wordpress site using the html block on the gutenberg editor, but everytime i save my html sheet i have this error "The response is not a valid JSON response." but it happens only with the html block, what could be wrong and how could i fix it?
I already tried upgrading the memory limit on php but it didnt workedt, neither the changes on my .htaccess file

what does the JSON response to the request look like if it's not valid JSON? Have you checked this via the browser dev tools network panel?

When this has happened to me in the past, it's usually because I've got a plugin that's sending output when it shouldn't, like a shutdown action that I'm using for debugging. Does it happen with all plugins turned off and a default theme (eg Twenty Twenty Four) in use?

I've seen this in the past with bad HTML and/or garbage characters in the block.

this is what appears on the console "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://ladolceria.cl/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://ladolceria.cl' and URL 'https://ladolceria.cl/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit'.
at post.php?post=2&action=edit:208:19"
